# How to dynamically save stdout into a variable, a list, or a numpy array?

Tags: python, serial-port

That's the code I've wrote so far is:

```
import subprocess
from io import StringIO
import sys

sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()
result = subprocess.run(['python', '-m', 'serial.tools.miniterm', 'COM3'])
mystdout.getvalue()
```

I have an Arduino on a serial port that spits out data and from research, I've done so  far I've found out that I can use

```
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()
#...
mystdout.getvalue()
```

to save stdout into a variable but the problem is that the serial port is always giving data so `mystdout.getvalue()` will never run.

Is there a  way to save what the serial port prints to a variable, a list or a numpy array, say every time the serial port prints out another value, that is in a fixed delay that I can modify (currently it is 50ms)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to use `Popen` as it allows you to access the stdout while the command is running. `subprocess.run` executes a command and waits for it to finish.

Try this

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['python', '-m', 'serial.tools.miniterm', 'COM3'],
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)

for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b""):
    parsed_line = line.decode().strip()

process.wait()
```